# ASP.Net MVC "Could Not Load Type" when executing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a very simple ASP.Net MVC Application that I have produced from an online tutorial. I've followed it exactly, step by step and have tried multiple times but keep getting the same error when I execute the code.

The program just displays an index page which lists a series of data from an sql server database using linq to sql.

This is the error:

Could not load type 'MvcApplication1.Views.Home.Index'.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: More info is required. Maybe post the stack trace

Comment: Do you have an index.aspx in your home folder?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Possible answer here:

http://www.jondavis.net/techblog/post/2009/04/29/Set-Up-IIS-For-An-MVC-App-When-All-Else-Fails-Check-View-Config.aspx

Basically, add the Views directory's web.config to your target Views directory. Although, it doesn't sound like you're using a strongly typed view, or aren't deploying your code.

Also, I have seen this problem also appear if the compile settings are removed from web.config. In an ASP.NET MVC project created in Visual Studio 2008, those settings are included in web.config, and they should remain or else this error will occur.

Comment: This looks like the solution to a similar problem I've been having, cheers (+1)

Comment: I had a similar problem caused by the absense of a PageParserFilterType attribute on the pages element of the web.config in the Views folder.  Best thing is to create a blank project and check that file.

Comment: @Will - Had the same issue...created a new project and copied the web.config in the Views folder over to the existing project.   @stimpy77 - +1 for leading us in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the current version of MVC? There was a big update in the Release Candidate that removed the code-behinds on views.

I ran into the same issue. Uninstalling MVC, then reinstalling fixed the problem for me. This can be done in Control Panel --> Add/Remove Programs.

Hope this helps,
Adam

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar "Could Not Load Type" problem with ASP.NET MVC in my Global.asax. The fix was to ensure the case of the inherits property was the same as the class it was referencing -- I didn't realize it was case sensitive!

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a pretty ambiguous error to me.  What hints does your Stack Trace give you?  What framework method throws the exception?